# Grouping within a group

Tags: teradata

My table:

```
select * from A
```

[image]

The output I want:

Per userid, per month, the top 2 categories, based on views descending.

In tabular form this would be:

[image]

I tried this, but I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong

```
select userid, category, month, views
from A
qualify
row_number() over (partition by userid, category, month order by views desc) = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean this:

```
select userid, category, month, views
from A
qualify
row_number() over (partition by userid, month order by views desc) <= 2
```